# Does an async function inside a lambda need to be awaited inside the lambda?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, lambda

In the code below, is there a difference between the calls in `WithoutInnerAwait`and `WithInnerAwait`?

Or in other words:

When using a lambda to wrap an async function, do I need to mark the lambda as async and use await inside? Or is it enough to simply await the lambda when it's called?

```cs
private async Task DoStuff(Func<Task> lambda)
{
    await lambda();
}

public async Task WithoutInnerAwait()
{
    await DoStuff(() => Task.Delay(5000));
}

public async Task WithInnerAwait()
{
    await DoStuff(async () => await Task.Delay(5000));
}
```

Comment: The only observable difference is when exceptions are thrown and what the stack trace would contain.

Comment: I've marked your question as a duplicate of two others. Taking `WithoutInnerAwait`, your code is essentially the same as `await DoStuff(SomeMethod);` where `SomeMethod` is declared as `public Task SomeMethod() { return Task.Delay(5000); }`. Your `WithInnerAwait` is the same except the `SomeMethod` would be async and contain `await`. As such, your question is really about the difference between returning `Task` and awaiting.

Comment: Check out the article [Eliding Async and Await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html) by Stephen Cleary. It's quite informative about this topic.